# is there a good guide that explains how to allow users to register/login using Twitter on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm looking for a step by step guide. I looked at various videos on youtube, searched the net, read articles, and read threads here but I'm still having some issues. I decided to scrap what I had as they were causing errors and start over.

I already registered my app on dev.twitter.com and I'm trying to use the Twitter and Oauth gems. I have also created this in my database:

```
create_table "twitter_accounts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "active",               :default => false
    t.text     "stream_url"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.string   "oauth_token_secret"
    t.string   "oauth_token_verifier"
    t.text     "oauth_authorize_url"
    t.datetime "created_at",                              :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                              :null => false
  end
```

Is there a good guide to use that is easy to follow?

Answer (score 3):

Try [`OmniAuth`](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) which works with twitter, facebook & other OAuth providers.

Here is a nice Railscast which details how to integrate twitter login using `omniauth`
http://railscasts.com/episodes/359-twitter-integration

Comment: I saw that link before, but it looks like you have to pay to view?

Comment: yup, but its $9bucks or you can grab the same video from *ahem* *ahem* sources. your choice  ;)

Comment: @GaurishSharma +1 for OmniAuth ..although thr is one free nut as well from nettuts http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Rails 3 in action book. 
n this book very detailed considered this issue
In this book you you will have login with Twiter and Github ( but this book has a few bugs -> but you can fix this bug very simple )